# Azure Powershell script to clone NSG rules across subscriptions in the same Tenant

Tags: powershell, azure

I need some help with a powershell script clone NSG rules from a particular NSG in 1 subscription to a NSG in another subscription. I have a script that accomplishes this if both NSG's are in the same subscription but not if they are in different subscriptions. Here is what I have. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#name of NSG that you want to copy 
$nsgOrigin = ""
#name new NSG  
$nsgDestination = "" 
#Resource Group Name of source NSG 
$rgName = "" 
#Resource Group Name when you want the new NSG placed 
$rgNameDest = ""
 
$nsg = Get-AZNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $nsgOrigin -ResourceGroupName $rgName 
$nsgRules = Get-AZNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg 
$newNsg = Get-AZNetworkSecurityGroup -name $nsgDestination -ResourceGroupName $rgNameDest 
foreach ($nsgRule in $nsgRules) { 

$acl = @{Name = $nsgRule.Name; Protocol = $nsgRule.Protocol; SourcePortRange= $nsgRule.SourcePortRange; DestinationPortRange = $nsgRule.DestinationPortRange;Priority = $nsgRule.Priority;Direction = $nsgRule.Direction; Access = $nsgRule.Access; SourceApplicationSecurityGroup = $nsgRule.SourceApplicationSecurityGroups }


if ( $nsgRule.DestinationAddressPrefix.count -gt 0 ) { 
$acl  += @{DestinationAddressPrefix = $nsgRule.DestinationAddressPrefix }
} 
if ( $nsgRule.SourceAddressPrefix.count -gt 0 ) {
$acl  += @{SourceAddressPrefix = $nsgRule.SourceAddressPrefix }
}
if ( $nsgRule.SourceApplicationSecurityGroups.count -gt 0 ) {
$acl  += @{SourceApplicationSecurityGroup = $nsgRule.SourceApplicationSecurityGroups }
}
if ( $nsgRule.DestinationApplicationSecurityGroups.count -gt 0 ) {
$acl  += @{DestinationApplicationSecurityGroup = $nsgRule.DestinationApplicationSecurityGroups }
}


Add-AZNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -NetworkSecurityGroup $newNsg @acl
       
} 
Set-AZNetworkSecurityGroup -NetworkSecurityGroup $newNsg
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the subscription context before and after the origin nsg like this

Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName 'SUBNAME'

$nsg = Get-AZNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $nsgOrigin -ResourceGroupName $rgName
$nsgRules = Get-AZNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg

Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName 'SUBNAME'